# How to truncate the data to first 3 letter in data flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to truncate data if unit=code.

Input:

Country, unit

India, code

Bangladesh, money

China, code

Output:

Country, unit

Ind, code

Bangladesh, money

Chi, code

What I tried?

I used case expression in dataflow but not able to truncate data to 3 letter code

Comment: What is the error in Case statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can use left() function in dataflow to get the first three characters of data.
- I repro'd this with sample input.

**Source data:**

[image]

- Derived column transformation is taken and expression for country column is given as `case(unit=='code',left(Country,3) , Country)`

**Derived column settings:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]